# Type Inference failed, but cannot check for instance of erased type

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have some logic that runs only when an object read from in FileInputStream is a Map:

```
  private fun loadEncryptedFile(file: File, password: CharArray) {


        var decrypted: ByteArray? = null
        ObjectInputStream(FileInputStream(file)).use {

            when (val data = it.readObject()) {
                is Map<*, *> -> {

                    if (data.containsKey("iv") && data.containsKey("salt") && data.containsKey("encrypted")) {
                        val iv = data["iv"]
                        val salt = data["salt"]
                        val encrypted = data["encrypted"]
                        if (iv is ByteArray && salt is ByteArray && encrypted is ByteArray) {
                            decrypted = Encryption().decrypt(
                                    hashMapOf("iv" to iv, "salt" to salt, "encrypted" to encrypted), password)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Every instance of the "data" variable gives me a "Type inference failed, the value of parameter K should be mentioned in input types" error.

However, replacing the wild cards with those types gives me the "Cannot check for instance of erased types" error. Where does the compiler want me to tell it what types are contained in the Map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awkward situation.

A bit of experimentation found one approach that seems to work: casting the map to a specific type *after* the `is Map<*, *>` check:

```
        when (val data = it.readObject()) {
            is Map<*, *> -> {
                val castData = data as Map<Any, Any>
                if (castData.containsKey("iv") && data.containsKey("salt") && castData.containsKey("encrypted")) {
                    val iv = castData["iv"]
                    // ...
```

This gives an ‘Unchecked cast’ warning, but it's not an error (and you can probably suppress it).

Comment: Odd. Good enough for now, though. Thank you!